# process collection_select on controller update actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select, controller

I have 2 models

The first model **category.rb**

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document

 # Relationships
  has_many :boards, :dependent => :destroy , :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards

  #fields
  field :name

  #attr
  attr_accessible :name, :boards_attributes
end
```

The second model its **board.rb**

```
class Board
 include Mongoid::Document

#Relationships
 belongs_to :category

  #fields
  field :name
  field :description

  #attr
  attr_accessible :name, :description

end
```

I have in **edit board view** the next form:

```
<%= form_for [@board], :url => user_board_path do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 <%= f.text_area :description, :cols =>72, :rows => 5, %>
 <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name%>
<% end %>
```

and I have in **update action from boards_controller.rb** the next:

```
def update
  @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @board.category_id = @category

 respond_to do |format|
   if @board.update_attributes(params[:board])
     format.html { redirect_to user_board_path(@board.user, @board), notice: 'Board was successfully updated.' }
     format.json { head :ok }
   else
     format.html { render action: "edit" }
     format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

**Why I get the @board.category_id nil? I want update the @board.category_id with the value that I choose in select**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `@board.category_id = @category` (you set an Object to an id field). It should be

```
@board = Board.find(params[:id])
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
@board.category = @category
```

or if `@category` is not used in the controller nor in the view, you could write

```
@board = Board.find(params[:id])
@board.category_id = params[:category_id]
```

The second solution removes a "SELECT" request on the Categories

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick , Does not works for me :(. I get in log `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_id`.

Comment: Tha problem was fixed :D. I have added **:category_id** to Board Model: `attr_accessible :name, :pins_attributes, :description, :category_id` Thank you very much!